# Move qcow2 image to physical hard drive

Tags: storage, cloning, qemu

I have a qcow2 image that I use to boot an installation of linux using QEMU; I would like to place the contents of that image directly onto a physical hard drive so that I can boot to that linux installation directly from my desktop. I would like to do something like `dd if=my-qcow2.img of=/dev/sdb`. However, this will clearly not work since qcow2 does not store the contents of the virtual disk in logical order within the qcow2 file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

QEMU comes with the [`qemu-img`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img) program to [convert between image formats](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Images#Converting_image_formats).

```
qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O raw my-qcow2.img /dev/sdb
```

Comment: Pay attention that the QCOW2 format is Compressed!  That means a 200GB QCOW2 image can convert into a 500GB hard drive...  That may cause the "device is too small" error you are receiving imho

Comment: Old question, but: qemu-img nowadays features the `dd` subcommand, which I found slightly easier to understand. For example: `qemu-img dd -f qcow2 -O raw bs=4M if=/vm-images/image.qcow2 of=/dev/sdd1`. It works just like the usual standalone `dd` program.

Comment: It's failing with `error while converting raw: Cannot grow device files` error.

Comment: @recolic That means that the destination disk is smaller than the uncompressed image.